# How to display a list of wordpress authors in a dropdown, with a link to the author template?

Tags: wordpress, list, drop-down-menu, author

I'm looking for a way to display the authors of a wordpress blog as a dropdown menu, with an on change event that redirects the user to the author page, which lists all the previous posts written by that user.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** Actually, you should simply be able to use wp_list_authors() for the whole thing, as it automatically generates a list of authors with a link to a page displaying all their posts. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_authors#Markup_and_Styling_of_Author_Lists for more details.

I'm using this plugin to display posts-by-author and it works well. http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/posts-by-author-plugin-for-wordpress/

I have an author.php template which displays the author's info (pic, blurb) and below it I'm showing their 5 most recent posts using the plugin above.

To show the pic I'm using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-photo/

To get the dropdown contents you could use this wp function:

```
<?php wp_list_authors(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has now added a function to do this:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_users( $args ); ?>
```

You just have to enter in your arguments.  If you need a sample of this in an HTML form with a submit button, there is one here http://bit.ly/wWunIE

Hope that helps.